# How do I create a presigned link to a particular version of an object using the Ruby AWS SDK v2?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using [the Ruby AWS SDK (v2)](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) to upload log files to a versioned S3 bucket.  The log files are not public, but I would like to generate a presigned link to the log to make it available for a limited time via a chat integration.  I want to link to a particular version, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098263/aws-cdn-create-signed-url-for-specific-s3-object-version) says is possible via the S3 console.

Documentation on [`Aws::S3::Presigner`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html) shows how to do this for an unversioned object (or the head version of a versioned object) but not for a particular version. The possible parameters to `#presigned_url` are not well documented, and reading the source it looks like the parameters are just passed to [`Seahorse::Client::Base#build_request`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Seahorse/Client/Base.html#build_request-instance_method) which is not S3-specific.

Comment: Yow, that documentation is painful to drill through, and this case is a poster child for why I wrote all my own AWS libraries.  A signed URL can definitely reference a apecific version of the object, which is included as `versionId=xxxxxx` in the query string.  The query string is part of the input to the signature algorithm, so this can' be just tacked on, of course. Does passing it as `version_id` do anything useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've finally worked this out, though I'm still not sure I could trace the entire code path.  In short: You can pass `:version_id` in the options parameter to `presigned_url`.

```rb
#
# Uploads a log to S3 at the given key, returning a URL
# to the file that's good for one hour.
#
# @param [String] bucket
# @param [String] key
# @param [String] body of the log to be uploaded
# @param [Hash] options
# @return [String] public URL of uploaded log, valid for one hour
# @raise [Exception] if the S3 upload fails
#
def upload_log(bucket, key, body, options={})
  # Upload log
  result = AWS::S3.create_client.put_object(
    options.merge(
      bucket: bucket,
      key: key,
      body: body
    )
  )

  # Get presigned URL that expires in one hour
  options = {bucket: bucket, key: key, expires_in: 3600}
  options[:version_id] = result[:version_id] unless result[:version_id].nil?
  Aws::S3::Presigner.new.presigned_url(:get_object, options)
end
```

And here, everything I could trace about why this works:

1. `presigned_url` passes its `params` argument through to `@client.build_request` ([presigner.rb#L48](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/s3/presigner.rb#L48)).
2. [`build_request`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb#L34) eventually pushes those parameters onto `request.context.params` of the request it returns (documented in [client/base_spec.rb#L91](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/ef9f2d3655c4bacb3adff580a6b295df510f78fe/aws-sdk-core/spec/seahorse/client/base_spec.rb#L91)).
3. From here my understanding is fuzzy; I expect that something like [Aws::Rest::Request::Builder](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/ef9f2d3655c4bacb3adff580a6b295df510f78fe/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/rest/request/builder.rb) passes all the params along to create the [`Endpoint`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/rest/request/endpoint.rb) and the particular rules for this operation (which I'm unable to find) allow `version_id` to be added to the querystring.

In any case, it's working.  Thanks for the pointer Michael!